# How often do directions services update their OSM data?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox, direction

Not sure if this is the right place to ask but I figured I would give it a shot. I'm working on an interactive map for a campus, I performed some edits to openstreetmaps and I can see the changes on OSM but not through third party direction services such as Mapbox and Mapzen. When I try to navigate they still follow the old paths.

I have performed smaller edits in the past and Mapbox's directions service seemed to pickup on them within a few hours to a day. I'm just wondering if there is any concrete information on this, I wasn't able to find anything when I searched.

Comment: You should only ask one question.  If you need answers for another direction service please open another question.  I have provided an answer to Mapbox because you specifically gave an example for that service.

Comment: Thanks for you response, I will keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/mapbox-streets-v6/) (google search term = 'mapbox update frquency')

**Data updates**

The current supported version of the Mapbox Streets vector tiles receives regular data updates as new information becomes available and existing information is improved.

> **Layer       (Source)                        Update frequency**
>
> most layers (OpenStreetMap replication feed) every 5 minutes
>
> admin (custom OpenStreetMap processing) irregular schedule;every 2-6 months
>
> water 'ocean parts'   (OpenStreetMap Data) irregular schedule;every 2-6 months
>
> marine_label, country_label, state_label (custom data) rarely, as needed

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's just interesting because I can see my changes appearing on OSM, on Mapbox Maps, but their directions service doesn't seem to be picking up on my new paths yet.

Comment: Have you tried to contact them about it?

Comment: This answer is not really useful since vector tiles are not used for route calculation.

Comment: agreed at this point because we can only assume that Custom processing also updates the routing/directions every 2-6 months.

Comment: I haven't tried to contact them about it, the last time I made changes it did take a few hours/days. I was just wondering if they had specifics regarding navigation published anywhere, but I guess not. Anyhow, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Each service has a different update interval which can range from hours to days and even to weeks. You need to check each service in particular to find out its update interval.

At least [GraphHopper](http://graphhopper.com), [OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/) and [brouter](http://brouter.de/) should update their data fairly often. I don't know the exact update intervals but your changes should be visible within a few days or maybe a week.

Comment: Thanks - I can confirm the changes did kick into Mapbox Directions a couple of days after being added to OSM.